# How to get rid of the space between the navbar and heading image

Tags: html, css

As the title states, I am having difficulty trying to get rid of the space between my navbar and header (the sky image). I thought the solution had something with setting one of the nav css (or ul) margin to auto or 0, but I'm still relatively new to css and html.
http://jsfiddle.net/Karmatix/ynf5xfts/4/

```css
body {
 background-color: #6f8285;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 1280px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

img {
 width: 1280px;
 height: 150px;
}


nav {
 background-color: black;
}

nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
 display: inline;
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 100px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: red;
}

a:hover {
 color: #6f6f6f;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Karmatix</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="karmatix.css">
 <script src="karmatix.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Cloud_banner.jpg">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Test 4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make your img `display:block` and add `margin-top:0;` to you nav ul: http://jsfiddle.net/ynf5xfts/5/

Comment: `nav ul { margin: 0; } img { vertical-align: middle; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style:

```css
img { vertical-align: middle; /* added */ }
nav ul { margin:0; /*added*/ }
```

### [Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ynf5xfts/7/)

Comment: Displaying all images as block may cause trouble. I'd rather position them vertically to top, middle or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css styles:

```
ul{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Ul has a auto margin of 16 px; from html

Answer (score 0):

remove the margin above your nav ul

```
nav ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```